# How to parse the error message in Throwable in Android

Tags: android, parsing, throwable

I get the error message string(ex.getMessage()) from Throwable in Android like below

{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

What is the best way to get only the message part from this error message string?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON parser like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and create class `ErrorMessage` like this

```
public class ErrorMessage{

private String message;

public getMessage(){
    return message;
    }
}
```

Then you just parse it using Gson:

`Gson gson = new Gson();
String error = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ErrorMessage.class);`